Trouble installing revenuecat on a Quasar/Capacitor app for IOS
I'm trying to install RevenueCat on an iOS app that is built with Quasar/Capacitor.
I created a Quasar boot file based on this information: https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/getting-started/installation/capacitor [SEE VUE SECTION]
export default boot(async ({ app, router }) => {
const configure = async () => {
try {
  await Purchases.setLogLevel({ level: LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG });
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
}

try {
    await Purchases.configure({
      apiKey: "key",      
    });   

 } catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
 }
};

When using the app through a mobile simulation via xcode, the bootfile throws an error: {"code":"UNIMPLEMENTED"}
What I think this means is that I have not correctly implemented it for use with iOS.
src-capacitor package.json
"dependencies": {
  "@capacitor/app": "^6.0.0",
  "@capacitor/cli": "^6.0.0",
  "@capacitor/core": "^6.2.0",
  "@capacitor/ios": "^6.2.0",
  "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^6.0.0",
  "@revenuecat/purchases-capacitor": "^9.0.9"
 }

package.json
 "dependencies": {
   "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.3",
   "@capacitor/app": "^6.0.2",
   "@capacitor/cli": "^6.0.0",
   "@capacitor/core": "^6.2.0",
   "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.4",
   "@revenuecat/purchases-capacitor": "^9.0.9",
   "pinia": "^2.0.11",
   "quasar": "^2.6.0",
   "vue": "^3.0.0",
   "vue-router": "^4.0.0",
  },

Any suggestions where to look?
